# prism PopupWindowAction within UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

How to hide Min, Max, Close buttons on prism PopupWindowAction?

```
<UserControl .........

<prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding NotificationRequest, Mode=OneWay}">            
       <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True"/>
</prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
```

I have tried following

```
<prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True">
            <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="Window">
                    <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize"/>
                    <Setter Property="SizeToContent" Value="WidthAndHeight"/>
                </Style>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowStyle>
</prism:PopupWindowAction>
```

But it has build error:
"The member "WindowStyle" is not recognized or is not accessible"

Comment: Can you update the question to include the whole `InteractionRequestTrigger` XAML block, all together? It would be nice to see what `xmlns:prism` is being set to as well.

Comment: Also, make sure you are using the latest version of Prism v6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit from Prism PopupWindowAction and write your own implementation.

I once wrote a CustomPopupWindowAction with the following features:

- CustomPopupWindowAction is borderless. No MinMaxHide buttons
- You can drag it around by left mouse button
- Dragging around is limited to the borders of the shell
- Moving the shell also moves the CustomPopupWindowAction
- You can have multiple CustomPopupWindowAction
- MinWidth and MinHeight of the shell is calculated, so the shell never "loses" its CustomPopupWindowActions

To give you an idea here is my example:

**How to use it in XAML**

```
<interact:Interaction.Triggers>

    <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger x:Name="_PopUpDialog" SourceObject="{Binding Path=PopUpDialog, Mode=OneWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

        <local:CustomPopUpWindowAction 
                                        WindowContent="{Binding Path=TargetView, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        CenterOverAssociatedObject="True"
                                        IsModal="False"
        >

        </local:CustomPopUpWindowAction >

    </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>

</interact:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**C#**

```
public class CustomPopUpWindowAction: PopupWindowAction
{
    private Window _Shell = null;
    private List<Window> _Windows = new List<Window>();
    private double _Top = 0;
    private double _Left = 0;


    public CustomPopUpWindowAction()
    {
        _Shell = Application.Current.Windows[0];
        _Top = _Shell.Top;
        _Left = _Shell.Left;
        _Shell.LocationChanged += _Shell_LocationChanged;
        _Shell.SizeChanged += _Shell_SizeChanged;
    }

    ~CustomPopUpWindowAction() 
    {
        _Shell.LocationChanged -= _Shell_LocationChanged;
        _Shell.SizeChanged -= _Shell_SizeChanged;

        foreach (Window w in _Windows)
        {
            w.MouseLeftButtonDown += OnChildWindowLeftMouseButtonDown;
            w.Closed += OnChildWindowClosed;
            w.LocationChanged += OnChildWindowPositionChanged;
        }
    }

    private void _Shell_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window shell = sender as Window;

        if (shell != null)
        {
            Double minWidth = 0;
            Double minHeight = 0;

            Double maxLeft = 0;
            Double maxLeftWith = 0;
            Double maxTop = 0;
            Double maxTopHeight = 0;

            Double border = 10;

            foreach (Window w in _Windows)
            {
                if (w.Left > maxLeft)
                {
                    maxLeft = w.Left;
                    maxLeftWith = w.Width;
                }
                if (w.Top > maxTop)
                {
                    maxTop = w.Top;
                    maxTopHeight = w.Height;
                }
            }

            minWidth = maxLeft + maxLeftWith - shell.Left + border;
            minHeight = maxTop + maxTopHeight - shell.Top + border;

            if (shell.Width < minWidth) shell.Width = minWidth;
            if (shell.Height < minHeight) shell.Height = minHeight;
        }
    }

    private void _Shell_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Window window = sender as Window;
        if (window != null)
        {
            Double differenceTop = _Top - window.Top;
            Double differenceLeft = _Left - window.Left;

            foreach (Window w in _Windows)
            {
                w.Top = w.Top - differenceTop;
                w.Left = w.Left - differenceLeft;
            }

            _Top = window.Top;
            _Left = window.Left;
        }
    }


    protected override Window CreateWindow()
    {
        _Windows.Add(base.CreateWindow());

        int index = _Windows.Count -1;

        _Windows[index].Owner = _Shell;

        _Windows[index].WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;

        _Windows[index].AllowsTransparency = true;

        _Windows[index].WindowStyle = System.Windows.WindowStyle.None;

        _Windows[index].BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);

        _Windows[index].ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;

        _Windows[index].MouseLeftButtonDown += OnChildWindowLeftMouseButtonDown;

        _Windows[index].Closed += OnChildWindowClosed;

        _Windows[index].LocationChanged += OnChildWindowPositionChanged; 

        _Windows[index].Tag = index;

        return _Windows[index];
    }

    private void OnChildWindowPositionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double topBorder = 60;
        double leftBorder = 10;
        double rightBorder = 10;
        double bottomBorder = 10;

        Window window = sender as Window;

        if (window != null)
        {
            if (window.Top < _Shell.Top + topBorder) window.Top = _Shell.Top + topBorder;
            if (window.Left < _Shell.Left + leftBorder) window.Left = _Shell.Left + leftBorder;

            double maxLeft = _Shell.Left + _Shell.ActualWidth - window.Width - rightBorder ;
            if (window.Left > maxLeft) window.Left = maxLeft;

            double maxTop = _Shell.Top + _Shell.ActualHeight - window.Height - bottomBorder;
            if (window.Top > maxTop) window.Top = maxTop;
        }
    }

    private void OnChildWindowLeftMouseButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Window window = sender as Window;
        if (window != null)
        {
            window.DragMove();
        }
    }

    private void OnChildWindowClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Window window = sender as Window;
        if (window != null)
        {
            window.MouseLeftButtonDown -= OnChildWindowLeftMouseButtonDown;
            window.Closed -= OnChildWindowClosed;
            window.LocationChanged -= OnChildWindowPositionChanged;
            _Windows.Remove(window);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course there is still a lot of room for improvements and some refactorings for better readability, but it works well.

For your own custom implementation just look in CreateWindow();

***Have fun playing around with it!***

By the way: Of course, with this implementation, you have to take care, that your shown controls inherit from IInteractionRequestAware, so that you can finish the interaction.